# Call function in ViewController after RelationshipSegue

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am having a multiple `UIViewController` embedded in a `UITabbarController`.
These are connected by Relationship Segues.

The starting point, `VC1` initially loads data and is then processed to a "detail" view.
Whenever I change tabs and go back to `VC1`, the application gets stuck, as `viewDidLoad` is not called.

Is there a way to trigger a function each time `VC1` is segued to?

Comment: use viewWillAppear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the application gets stuck, as viewDidLoad is not called

The application is not stuck. It is working perfectly. `viewDidLoad` is called when a view controller is *created* and *loads* its view. That only happens once in the life of the view controller. When you leave a view controller and come *back* to it, it is still there (i.e. it is not being created from scratch), so naturally `viewDidLoad` is not called.

If your goal is to hear about the fact that the tab bar controller is switching to VC1, give the tab bar controller a delegate and implement [tabBarController(_:didSelect:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621173-tabbarcontroller) or similar.

Even better, configure things so that there is no need to do this. If there is common data that is accessed by both view controllers, architect things so that a view controller sends new data *up* to a data controller and the data controller broadcasts news of the change *down* to all view controllers that need to know this.